# Display a value from an object based on an id in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently using a custom filter to display a name when a user id is displayed. So selected_user might be 5, so it then displays "bob" instead of "5":

```
{{ selected_user | display_name:users }}
```

The users object contains the entire users table.

The code:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
function xCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.users = [
   {"id":1, "name":"joe"},
   {"id":5, "name":"bob"},
   {"id":10, "name":"charlie"},
  ];
  $scope.select_user = function(user) {
   $scope.selected_user = user;
  }
}

angular.module('myApp').filter("display_name", function () {
    return function (user_id, users) {
    if(user_id) {
        return(users[users.map(function(x) { return x.id; }).indexOf(user_id)].name);
     }
    }
});
```

This works fine, but it feels like I am doing this inefficiently by passing the entire users object to the filter each time a name is displayed. Is there a better way to do this with filters or are filters the wrong approach?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h2rn3qnw/

Comment: I'm not seeing the logic of having that filter in your code so apologies if I'm missing the point but give this a try http://jsfiddle.net/ue8rw787/. You already have the `selected_user` object bound to `$scope` after the `ng-click` event, and that object has a name property. There is no need to filter all the users just to find the name, you can simply display the name using `selected_user.name`

Comment: The id is stored in a table, not the name. When I display the data elsewhere, I'd like a universal filter to convert that to a user friendly name. The ng-click is just for the demo purposes.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have the `ng-click` directive return the `$index`:

```
<div ng-repeat="user_data in users"
     ng-click="select($index)" class="selection">
{{ user_data.id }} - {{ user_data.name }} - {{$index}}
</div>
```

```
$scope.select = function(index) {
    $scope.selection = index;
};
```

```
Selected User ID: {{ users[selection].id }}<br>
Selected User Name: {{ users[selection].name }}
```

## The DEMO

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("xCtrl", function xCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.users = [
  {"id":1, "name":"joe"},
  {"id":5, "name":"bob"},
  {"id":10, "name":"charlie"},
  ];
  $scope.select = function(index) {
     $scope.selection = index;
  };
})
```

```css
.selection { color:blue; cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller="xCtrl">
    Users:<br>
    <div ng-repeat="user_data in users"
         ng-click="select($index)" class="selection">
    {{ user_data.id }} - {{ user_data.name }} - {{$index}}
    </div> <!-- ng-repeat -->
    <hr>
    Selected User ID: {{ users[selection].id }}<br>
    Selected User Name: {{ users[selection].name }}
  </div> <!-- ng-controller -->
</div> <!-- ng-app -->
```